# JavaScript array iteration - MDN example

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, increment

I was reading the re-introduction to JavaScript on the MDN website and came across this example in the Array section:

```
for (var i = 0, item; item = a[i++];){
   // Do something with item
}
```

Where "a[]" is an array being looped over.

I am confused about the value that "item" will have in its first iteration. As i=0 and item is at first undefined, then when it is assigned the value of a[i++] wouldn't the iteration start from i=1, which would mean that the iteration would start from the second element in the a[] array -> a[1], skipping over the first element a[0] entirely?

Comment: Note that as soon as the current element in the array is `0` or `false`, the loop will end.

Comment: This is one of the worst possible for loops I have seen in JavaScript before. You manage to save 1-2 characters. But sacrifice the usefulness of the index variable and readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i++` is the *post* increment operator, which means that it increments `i` by `1` but evaluates to the old (non-incremented) value.

```
> i = 0
  0
> i++
  0
> i
  1
```

Comment: Note that in some languages `++i` also exists, it does pre-incrementing, so it has the new value right away.

Comment: ++i also exists in JS if one would like to use it

Answer (score 2):

i++ is post increment (see other answers) and item will not be undefined, because the predicate (the second part in the for loop) is executed before each iteration.

```
for (var i = 0, item ; item = a[i++];) {
```

will evaluate to:

```
var i = 0;
var item;

item = a[i];  // loop
i += 1
if (!item) // exit loop
// loop body
// start again at loop
```

The problem with this syntax is, that if a value in `a` is falsy, the loop will terminate prematurely.

```
var a = [1,2,0,3,4];
for (var i = 0, item ; item = a[i++];) {
   console.log(item);
}
```

Will output "1 2" because "0" is falsy and the loop terminates

Comment: There are so many unexpectedly falsey values in JavaScript. Just look at [this](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/), for example.

Answer (score 1):

i++ means that javascript reads the i value and then increments it