# Clarification on JavaScript operator precedence when assigning and incrementing values

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence

Despite working with JavaScript for quite a while now I've only recently started reading up about [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), however I've stumbled across a bit of a wall which I can't seem to find an answer for.

Consider the following example:

```javascript
x=1;      // x === 1
x++;      // x === 2

x=1;      // x === 1
y=x++;    // x === 2, y === 1
```

If `++` has a higher precedence than `=`, how is `y` not becoming `2`?

Now consider:

```javascript
x=1;      // x === 1
y=++x;    // x === 2, y === 2
```

If `++x` and `x++` have identical associativity, how come `y` *is* becoming `2` in this case?

Here's an [accompanying Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/YxUDX/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16526692/139010

Comment: Do you know why this is called the *post* fix increment operator? That's why.

Comment: This must have been a *really* tough question since only people with 10,000+ rep answered it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `++` operator, when it appears **after** a variable or property reference, is a **post-increment** operation. That means that the value of the `++` subexpression is the value *before* the increment.

Thus it's not just operator precedence at work here. Instead, it's the basic semantics of the operator.

When `++` appears **before** the variable or property reference, it's a **pre-increment**. That means that the value of the subexpression is the already-incremented value of the variable or property.

Pre- and post-increment was part of the C programming language, and maybe one or more earlier languages. Some computer instruction sets have addressing modes with behaviors that are reminiscent of the effect of pre- and post-increment.

Comment: Ah, everything makes so much more sense now! Thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 2):

`x++` is a post-increment. It returns the current value of `x` and *then* increments it by one. `++x`, on the other hand, is a pre-increment. It increments the value of `x` by 1 and *then* returns the current  value of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the `++` *after* the variable performs a postfix incrementation.  The variable is incremented, but the *old* value is returned in the expression.

Putting the `++` *before* the variable is a prefix incrementation.  The incremented value is returned.  This has nothing to do with operator precedence.

[Further reading](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_pre_increment_and_post_increment_in_c_language)

Answer (score 0):

This is because `++x` and `x++` are *not* the same.

- `++x` increments `x` and returns the **new value**
- `x++` increments `x` and returns the **original value**